# How can I debug my code using opencv in QT creator?

Tags: qt, opencv, debugging

I use QT Creator IDE , it's debugger is active .
but when I add Opencv libraries , QT 's debugger becomes inactive ,
and it's output is "No debuger set up "

How can I debug my code in this situation ?

Comment: Did you link your program to OpenCV debug libs (the ones with `d` in the end)?

Comment: yes but it doesn't work .